# Can I leave a comment for a deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes I have **deleted answers** were deleted by a moderator or a trusted user and I want to leave comment for the moderator or users to get a feedback or say that I had improved my answer and it deserves to be undeleted.

I have two  questions about it:

- Can i leave that comment for a deleted post?
- if no, what should I do?

Comment: No, you can't comment or edit deleted posts.

Answer (score 4):

You can flag a deleted post. The only available flag is "other", which will let you enter a message that will get to the mods.

[image]